# ThreadStatic for .net compact framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework

How can we reproduce `ThradStatic` behavior in .net compact framework 3.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a static (in this case appdomain static) dictionary indexed by the thread id with associated getters and setters thtat index into the dictionary using Thread.Current.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LocalDataStoreSlot` class, that automatically discards the object when the Thread terminates.

Eg:

```
private static readonly LocalDataStoreSlot nameSlot = Thread.AllocateDataSlot();

public string Name
{
    get { return (string)Thread.GetData(nameSlot); }
    set { Thread.SetData(nameSlot, value); }
}
```